# Errors while launching web page through Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

When i was working with selenium webdriver by using Eclipse with java,I got some errors like 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)   at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)   at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2856)  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1668)   at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)   at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486).
How Can i fix them?
Thanks in adance.

Comment: what is your firefox and selenium versions and along with two share your code once